# Can I upgrade a Windows 7 student licence?

Tags: windows-8

I have a computer with a windows 7 student licence key, from the Microsoft Academic Alliance. Which I have from when I was studying. Is it possible to upgrade it to Windows 8? Or do I need to buy a retail licence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upgrade your Windows 7 student license to Windows 8.

The only requirement for the upgrade, as per the [terms and conditions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions), is that you have a valid base license. A student license is still a valid license.

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade it, but you will need to get a legitimate Windows 8 Key.

If you are part of the Dream Spark Premium, then you can use one of those. Otherwise you will need to purchase a retail upgrade key or full retail copy.

Answer (score 2):

So, far from what I've read, Microsoft is offering Windows 8 for two prices at this point - $15 and $40.

The first ($15) option is for owners of Windows 7 PCs which have been purchased after June 02, 2012. This page can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_SM_Meet_FPP_Null).

The second ($40) is for everyone else who is `running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, or Windows 7` and is a regular Windows 8 Pro Upgrade license. This price is only valid until January 31, 2012 and the page can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_SM_Meet_FPP_Null).

**So, essentially, yes - as long as you have a valid base install (Windows XP-7), you can upgrade to Windows 8.**

If you are still have access to Microsoft Academic Alliance* they can provide you with a license key for Windows 8.

- It is now known as [Dreamspark](http://dreamspark.com).

Comment: I'm not studying any more so no I'm not part of it

Comment: Then, you would have to purchase a $15 or $40 license (depending on when you bought the computer). But, yes you can upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to windows higher versions at any time. However, you need to buy the licence key for windows 8 upgrade unless or otherwise you have a windows 8 key from your DreamSpark (MSDNNA).